# How to find the highest minimum value in a python dictionary by creating another dictionary (not using builtin functions)

Tags: python, dictionary, minimum

Apologies if my question is too specific - I'm really stuck with this one.
I have created a dictionary called monthly_rainfall = {} using a tuple as a dict_key(state, month) and rainfall as the values

```
monthly_rainfall = {}
is_first_line = True
for row in open("climate_data_2017.csv"):
  if is_first_line:
  is_first_line = False
  else:
   values = row.split(",")
   rainfall = values[6]
   state = values[1]
   date = values[0]
   month = date[1]

   dict_key = (state, month)
   if dict_key not in monthly_rainfall:
    monthly_rainfall[dict_key] = [rainfall]
   else:
    monthly_rainfall[dict_key].append(rainfall)
```

I then want to find the minimum monthly rainfall in each state by create another dictionary called minimum_monthly_rainfall = {} rather than/without using inbuilt functions such as max or lambda

I then need to find the state with the highest minimum monthly rainfall and which month is occurred in.

I really appreciate any input.

Comment: tiny advice: if you are looking for the minimum you do need to save all  measurements for a (state,month), you only need to keep the smallest that would simplify your montly_rainfall structture.

Comment: dict is a built-in. you should be explicit in the functions that are allowed and those that are not.

Comment: (and tell your teacher that not allowing lambda is not a good filter: you're still asking SO to do your homework)